# Javascript regex .replace() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I vaguely learned how regex work earlier on my last question and thought that I would be able to use it with other strings. Apparently this is not the case. Below are the contents of a div called `mqcontainer`.

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://i.imgur.com/TeC4R.png"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/TeC4R.png" alt="Posted Image">[br]<small></small></a><small><a href="http://i.imgur.com/TeC4R.png" class="view_full">View Full Image</a></small>
```

My goal is to filter out this string so that it instead shows `[url=http://i.imgur.com/TeC4R.png]Image[/url]` when I click a button. This is what I have been trying:

```
$("#containerbtn").click(function(){
$("#mqcontainer").each(function(){
  $(this).html(
    $(this).html().replace(
      /<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="(.*?)"><img src=".*?" alt="Posted Image">\[br\]<small><\/small><\/a><small><a href=".*?" class="view_full">View Full Image<\/a><\/small>/g,
      '[url=$1]Image[/url]'
    )
  );
});
});
```

It is not working no matter what I try. Can anyone offer me some insight into the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wrong:**

```
$("#mqcontainer").each(function(){
  $(this).html(
    ...
  )};
)};
```

The code above can not be correct. Since there is only one div with the ID `mqcontainer`.

**Try this:**

```
$("#mqcontainer").html(
    $("#mqcontainer").html().replace(/<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="(.*?)"><img src=".*?" alt="Posted Image">\[br\]<small><\/small><\/a><small><a href=".*?" class="view_full">View Full Image<\/a><\/small>/g, '[url=$1]Image[/url]')
);
```

Comment: I'd argue on semantics that it **is** correct. The code will function perfectly since each is perfectly able to work on a single object collection. I will agree that it is bad code thoughand possibly indicative of errors if multiple things with the same ID are being used. Also I think that was more of a comment since it doesn't actually answer his question or help at all (well, you have a fixed regex at a glance but you didn't mention this change at all).

Answer (score 3):

the `[br]` should be escaped in the regexp:  `\[br\]`

Comment: ... No luck, though I should have caught that. Thanks.

Comment: This works for me: `'<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="http://i.imgur.com/TeC4R.png"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/TeC4R.png" alt="Posted Image">\[br\]<small></small></a><small><a href="http://i.imgur.com/TeC4R.png" class="view_full">View Full Image</a></small>'.replace(/<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="(.*?)"><img src=".*?" alt="Posted Image">\[br\]<small><\/small><\/a><small><a href=".*?" class="view_full">View Full Image<\/a><\/small>/, '[url=$1]Image[/url]')` You can run it in the Firebug Console. It uses the escaped \[br\].

Comment: @Makaze: you want to be careful of introducing bugs while correcting other bugs... As noted in my answer your edit introduces an extra `]` that wasn't in your pre-edit version. I've tested the string in my version (admittedly via .NET Regex) and it works and I believe is basically what Baldrick told you to use.

Comment: Chris: Typo, fixed. I have tried Baldric's. The current code in my question up to date and it is not working.

@powertac: I do not understand where to put that string. Can you use give me the full context?

My lack of knowledge grows ever more apparent. Sigh...

Answer (score 0):

```
<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="(.*?)"><img src=".*?" alt="Posted Image">\[br\]<small><\/small><\/a><small><a href=".*?" class="view_full">View Full Image<\/a><\/small>
```

The above should work.

I removed an extraneous ] that was after your image and before the escape [br].

**Edit**: And a note to add that looking at the revision history after seeing powtac's comments above this is in fact an error you introduced on editing in his suggestion.